# I need to find employee who earn highest salary more than average salary each of their companies

Tags: sql

My query gives me one 'company_name'  more than one time.
I trying to distinct it but couldn't

```
SELECT employee_name,company_name, AVG(salary) as 'Average'
FROM works
GROUP BY employee_name,company_name 
HAVING AVG(salary) > (SELECT AVG(salary) FROM works)
```

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: Insert into works values ('emp 1','First Bank Corporation',35000)
Insert into works values ('emp 2','Small Bank Corporation',38000)
Insert into works values ('emp 3','First Bank Corporation',36000)
Insert into works values ('emp 4','Nation Bank Corporation',35800)
Insert into works values ('emp 5','Small Bank Corporation',39200)
Insert into works values ('emp 6','First Bank Corporation',35900)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't apply your condition in the HAVING, but start with that.  You want the average salary per company correct?  So, if your data represents 20 companies, you want each employee within their respective company that has a salary higher than the average for that company.  So I first have the average per company, then join back to works and grab only those employees who have salary on-their-own higher than the average per same company.

```
select
      PreAvg.Company_Name,
      PreAvg.compAvgSalary,
      w.Employee_Name,
      w.Salary
   from
      ( select company_name, Avg( salary ) compAvgSalary
           from works
           group by company_name ) PreAvg
         JOIN Works w
            on PreAvg.Company_Name = w.Company_Name
            AND w.Salary = PreAvg.compAvgSalary
```

If you are looking for the HIGHEST Salary per company, that would be slightly different.  Select the MAXIMUM salary per company, then get only those employees that have that salary for that company.  Again, similar query.

```
select
      PreMax.Company_Name,
      PreMax.compMaxSalary,
      w.Employee_Name,
      w.Salary
   from
      ( select company_name, max( salary ) compMaxSalary
           from works
           group by company_name ) PreMax
         JOIN Works w
            on PreMax.Company_Name = w.Company_Name
            AND w.Salary = PreMax.compMaxSalary
```

Comment: But it give me same answer sir. I need to select one company_name one time only

Comment: @Pramu, although you accepted the answer, please edit your existing question with clarification of what you MEAN.  If your data has multiple companies, do you only want the one company with the highest average? And then only want the employee who has the highest from that company?  Or, do you really only care about the highest paid employee for any given company?  Per the implied original query, you were looking for company average and getting those above the average.  Many people could be over the given average for a single company.

Comment: @Pramu, revised to get the HIGHEST Salary per Company.  However, if you have 2 or more people with the same highest salary, it will grab both name instances.

Comment: Yeah. you are correct sir. I only want the All companies with the highest average And then only want the employee who has the highest from that each companies

Comment: @Pramu, clarify please.  Is your question properly resolved?  If no, are you really expecting only a single company record to be returned no matter how many companies?  And that company is the one company with the highest average? -- Again, only a Single company?  And from that the single employee from that company that has the highest salary?

Comment: Sir, My Table have four companies and they have many employees. so I need to find that who earn more than the average salary of their own companies but if some company have more than one employees ( earn more than of their own company average salary) so then I need to select the highest one through  of them.